# Need help on LINQ query left joins and multiple fields

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have the following SQL query that I would like to rewrite into LINQ:

```
SELECT gp.Name
 , r.DateOfRace
 , ISNULL(SUM(rr.Points), 0) AS Points
FROM Races r
INNER JOIN GrandPrix gp
 ON r.GrandPrixId = gp.GrandPrixId
LEFT JOIN Predictions p
 ON p.RaceId = r.RaceId
 AND p.AdditionalUserInformationId = 2
LEFT JOIN RaceResults rr
 ON p.DriverId = rr.DriverId
 AND p.FinishPosition = rr.FinishPosition
 AND p.RaceId = rr.RaceId
WHERE r.Season = 2010
GROUP BY gp.Name
 , p.RaceId
 , r.DateOfRace
```

And this is much I got, when it's still working:

```
from races in Races
join grandprix in GrandPrixes
on races.GrandPrixId equals grandprix.GrandPrixId
from Predictions in Predictions.Where(v => v.RaceId == races.RaceId).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
 DateOfRace = races.DateOfRace,
 GrandPrix = grandprix.Name,
}
```

When I go further, things go wrong - I can't for example get the `AND p.AdditionalUserInformationId = 2` right.

I hope somebody can help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
join p in Predictions
    on new { p.RaceId, p.AdditionalUserInformationId } =
       new { r.RaceId, AdditionalUserInformationId = 2 } into ps
from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
join rr in RaceResults
    on new { p.DriverId, p.RaceId, p.FinishPosition } =
       new { rr.DriverId, rr.RaceId, rr.FinishPosition } into rrs
from rr in rrs.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

You use the ability of C# to structurally compare anonymous types. Two anonymous types are created with the same properties, which makes them instances of the same class. These instances can then be compared.

Comment: Thank You (Dank je wel :-)) Ronald, this helped me a whole lot.

One last thing though - these joins produce inner joins instead of left. The syntax I put up in my post uses the .Where() method which actually did that. With this version this isn't applyable anymore, so... is there an easy solution?

Comment: Graag gedaan :) I've updated my answer so that it uses two left outer joins.

Comment: Da's fantastisch! (Fantastic!) You made a happy guy here Ronald!

Answer (score 1):

```
join grandprix in GrandPrixes
on new {races.GrandPrixId, p.AdditionalUserInformationId} equals new {grandprix.GrandPrixId,2}
```

Comment: This won't compile. You must give a name to each property in an anonymous type.